# How to monitor the Quartz task/trigger is alive?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, monitor, scheduler

I want to monitor a quartz job which will be fired at 18:00 per day....

This job is a vital function for us, how can we know the task will NOT be triggered correctly before it be fired?

yesterday, I try to change the trigger-time to per hour and use counter+time to do monitor, but fail...

Does quartz has some API for us to do this?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried implement TriggerListener or JobListener? http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-07

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Quartz job is available with lot of versions. You can use the API and monitor them.
Just click on following , you will get some idea.
http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/overview-tree.html